# Using iPhoneContacts library in App Store

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, iphone-privateapi

I tried publishing an app using https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/iPhoneContacts library. When validating the app for App Store review i have the following warning:

[image]

Any idea what can be done about it? Is it safe to publish anyway?

EDIT: fixed the library name, hadn't put the right one...

EDIT2: the first link was the right one actually

Comment: There's one solution - fix the library so it doesn't use the private API or renamed the method so it doesn't match the name of a private API.

Comment: Thanks, i'll fork the lib to fix this, but is it really risky? Since it doesn't use any private API, but is flagged by selector name? Also the selector name is pretty straightforward, i would expect that quite some apps using addressbook could use a selector like this.

Comment: PS: why is the question downvoted without explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you're not using a private API, but you've got a function with the same name as a private API.

To be safe, just change your function's name. This will avoid any complications that might arise. You can do this really quickly using Xcode's find and replace mechanism.